# No. of significant figures in absolute value w.r.t true value and relative percentage error

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, rounding-error, standard-error

To find the no. of a significant figure in absolute value $= 0.05411$ with respect to true value $= 0.05418$ and the relative percentage error.

**Here's my solution:**

[image]

But I ain't sure whether it's correct or not.
can someone help me out?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You’ve worked out the relative error correctly, although 0.13% is probably better than having all those decimal places.

Comment: If you said 0.05 you would mean between 0.045 and 0.055, which contains the true value. If you said 0.054 you would mean [0.0535, 0.0545] which contains the true value. If you said 0.0541 you would mean [0.05405,0.5415] which doesn’t contain the true value, so you only have 2 significant figures wrt the true value.